# Read Russian text from pdf and write in excel file

Tags: java, character-encoding, pdfbox

I am reading PDF written in Russian language and parsing using PDFBox into csv, but csv file contains question marks instead of Russian text.

I tried text encoding in inputstream "Windows-1252" new `InputStreamReader(fr, "Windows-1252");` also set `System.setProperty("console.encoding", "UTF-8");` but notings work.

```
    byte[] text = tc.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String encodedString = new String(text, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("result=" + encodedString );
```

I received result in console is PDF contains text like "Полное наименование"
result=???????????? ??????????
result=???????? ??????????

Comment: Can you show more of your code? And is it possible to make a sample PDF available? The part from `.getBytes(...` to `..., StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` can be removed. It converts a string to bytes and then back again. So it is without effect. And "Полное наименование" looks Russian, not German.

Comment: Полное именование is indeed Russian, not German.

Comment: Yes, it is Russian. And I am unable to provide PDF because of privacy issue. PDF contains tabular data I am try to export it in CSV.

Comment: I create a sample code now reading text from text file contains same Russian text and when I printing it it return question marks.
        System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
        try {
            FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("E:/a.txt");
            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(fr,"UTF-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
            System.out.println("output="+br.readLine());
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
        try {
            FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("E:/a.txt");
            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(fr,"UTF-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
            System.out.println("output="+br.readLine());
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

Comment: Most likely the issue is missing or incorrect information for text extraction in the document. An issue in pdfbox is less probable. As you are *unable to provide PDF because of privacy issue*, we cannot check for pdfbox issues here at all.

Comment: Now I am created a sample with text file which contains "Полное наименование" then try to print on console but same result is question mark.
`try { FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("E:/a.txt"); 
InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(fr,"UTF-8"); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir); System.out.println("output="+br.readLine()); br.close(); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: googling "java russian characters console question marks" brings several results that may help you, or show that there is no solution (for the console).

Comment: This is my test code, actual is I am converting PDF file written in Russian to csv file but csv contains question marks.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and suggestions , my problem was resolve. Actually problem was with ms office. Russian support was not enabled so it resulting raw value.